# Регулярное выражение, кирилические буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

вот таким вот регулярным выражением фильтрую русские буквы перед запросом в базу

```
preg_match('/[а-яА-Я]+/', $_GET['q'], $q);
```

но возникает какой то глюк при вводе кириллической буквы "р", посмотрел значения которые отдает регулярка

```
var_dump($q);
var_dump($_GET['q']);
```

оказалось что буква р заменяется ромбиков с вопросом внутри.
причем р глючит с любым набором символов

[image: pic]

почему так происходит?

Comment: Использовать флаг `u` в регулярке?

Comment: ага, хорошая идея

Answer (score 1):

Символ ромбика означает, что у вас русский UTF-8 символ, который занимает 2 байта, был рассечен пополам - это один байт, половинка русского символа UTF-8. Необходимо проследить, чтобы все компоненты вашей программы работали с UTF-8 символами корректно, например, в регулярных выражениях следует добавить модификатор u для поддержки UTF-8

```
'/[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+/u'
```

Для обработки строк следует использовать функции расширения mbstring.

Comment: У вас в регулярке, как и у автора вопроса, буквы русского языка перечислены только, а не кирилица, да и то не все. `/[а-яё]+/ui` - все буквы русского языка, `/\p{Cyrillic}+/u` - вся кирилица.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание поправил. Хотел обратить внимание на именно на расколотый символ UTF-8.